# Broadcast receiver does not receive intent

Tags: android

I would like a callback method in a non activity class to close any activity currently on the activity stack that belongs to the extending activity `PacketActivity`

```
public class PacketActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //...

}
```

Here is my call back method in the non activity class using a static reference to my main activity to send an an intent

```
// Sends an intent telling activities that extend PacketActivity to 
// call finish()
@Override
public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, 
    int newState) {

    if(newState == 0){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("closeActivity",0);
    MainActivity.mMainActivity.sendBroadcast(intent);   
    } 
}
```

My broadcast receiver is registered in `PacketActivity`, however `onReceive` method is never invoked. Any idea why? Thanks.

```
public class PacketActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = PacketActivity
        .class
        .getSimpleName();

    protected static final String NAME_OF_ACTION = "closeActivity";

    // Declare a custom broadcast receiver
    protected BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = 
        new BroadcastReceiver() {

        // Listens for the intent indicating that this activity, 
        // and importantly, any extending activity should be closed.
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Intent received");
            if (intent.getAction().equals(NAME_OF_ACTION)) {
                Log.v(TAG,"Closing activity");
                finish();
            }
        }
    };

    // Register the broadcast receiver in the onCreate
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.v(TAG,"onCreate");
        Log.v(TAG,"Registering receiver");
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, 
            new IntentFilter(NAME_OF_ACTION));
    }

    // Unregister the receiver in the onPause method to prevent 
    // memory leak
    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        Log.v(TAG,"onPause");
        Log.v(TAG,"Unregistering receiver");
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

**edit**

I tried adding an action string like this, with no results

```
// Sends an intent telling activities that extend PacketActivity to 
// call finish()
@Override
public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, 
    int newState) {

    if(newState == 0){
    Intent intent = new Intent("closeActivity"); // Add action string to intent
    MainActivity.mMainActivity.sendBroadcast(intent);   
    } 
}
```

Comment: Is `onConnectionStateChange` getting triggered? Btw referring a static reference which is present in an activity is a bad approach and may cause leaks. Try using `LocalBroadCastManager` ? Make sure your intent which you are passing around has an action

Comment: @Vivek_Neel Thanks, I just added the action string in my intent, you can see my edit at the bottom.

Comment: It should be `intent.setAction(..)`

Comment: @Vivek_Neel thank it worked. Reading the docs, I assumed that I could just initialize an intent with a string, and it would be added as an action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Intent` that you are broadcasting has no action string. It will match nothing. In particular, it will not match an `IntentFilter` for `NAME_OF_ACTION`.

Also, **please** do not use system broadcasts for an in-process event bus. Use `LocalBroadcastManager`, a suitable `LiveData` object, greenrobot's EventBus, or something similar.

Comment: Thanks, I added the action string with no results, you can see my edit.